# Batch alter Relationship Contact Permission only

Tags: api, permissions, relationships

While trying to alter Contact Relationships Permission ("Contact A can view and update information about Contact B") using this code:

```
$result = civicrm_api3('Relationship', 'create', array(
  'debug' => 1,
  'contact_id_a' => 111,
  'contact_id_b' => 111,
  'relationship_type_id' => 111,
  'id' => 111,
'is_permission_a_b' => 0, /* <- This was manually set as 1 and need to be altered */ 
));
```

we've got "duplicate relationship" error message

```
"error_message": "Duplicate Relationship"
```

Deprecated "setvalue/update" suggestion is *"Use "create" with an id instead."* and we do have all IDs in place.  Does 'Create' for Relationships work as it works for Contacts or we've missed something?

**UPDATE 1**
After some debugging it has turned that  we have exactly same situation described here [How to change the direction of a relationship type with existing data](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/6725/how-to-change-the-direction-of-a-relationship-type-with-existing-data?rq=1) , but we weren't aware that changing Relationship direction via GUI doesn't make change in a database. Sounds like another civicrm bug.

**UPDATE 2**
Even after Relationship directions have been altered, same error "Duplicate Relationships" appears at an attempt to ALTER one of Relationship parameter  using CREATE Action via CiviCRM Api.

Comment: Did you try the action update? Sometimes there is a difference between create and update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some debugging it has turned that  we have exactly same situation described here [How to change the direction of a relationship type with existing data](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/6725/how-to-change-the-direction-of-a-relationship-type-with-existing-data?rq=1) , but we weren't aware that changing Relationship direction via GUI doesn't make change in a database. Sounds like another civicrm bug.

We've ended up by direct Mysql intervention with this query (in case someone will face this issue in future):

```
UPDATE 
 civicrm_relationship 
SET 
  contact_id_a=contact_id_a+contact_id_b,
  contact_id_b=contact_id_a-contact_id_b,
  contact_id_a=contact_id_a-contact_id_b
WHERE ** ... conditions set ...  **
```